# MPI_Get hangs in loop due to different loop length

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm learning to use MPI_Get in loops, but the program freezes because one loop ends, and the other did not. Here is a simple code that I made to recreate the issue

```
using vector_real = std::vector<double>;                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  int total_rank, rank;                                                                                                                                                                                            
  int N=5;                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);                                                                                                                                                                                          
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &total_rank);                                                                                                                                                                      
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  vector_real Array(N-rank);                                                                                                                                                                                       
  double a ;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  for (int i=0; i<N-rank; i++){                                                                                                                                                                                    
    Array[i] = rank;                                                                                                                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  MPI_Win windowX;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  MPI_Win_create(&Array[0], N, sizeof(double), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &windowX);                                                                                                                           
  MPI_Win_fence(0, windowX);                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  std::cout << "rank=" << rank<< " starts MPI_Get with loop length="<< N-rank << "\n";                                                                                                                                                                               
  
  for (int i=0; i<N-rank; i++){                                                                                                                                                                                    
    MPI_Win_fence(0, windowX);                                                                                                                                                                                     
    MPI_Get(&a, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 2, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, windowX);                                                                                                                                                      
    MPI_Win_fence(0, windowX);                                                                                                                                                                                     
    std::cout <<"rank="<< rank << " got a =" << a <<"\n";                                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  std::cout <<"rank="<< rank<<" ended !!!\n";                                                                                                                                                                      
  MPI_Finalize();                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

The output looks like this

```
mpirun -np 2 ./test.o                                                                                                                                                                                              
rank=0 starts MPI_Get with loop length=5                                                                                                                                                                           
rank=1 starts MPI_Get with loop length=4                                                                                                                                                                           
rank=1 got a =0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rank=1 got a =0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rank=0 got a =0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rank=0 got a =0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rank=0 got a =0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rank=1 got a =0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rank=1 got a =0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rank=1 ended !!!                                                                                                                                                                                                   
rank=0 got a =0
```

We see that rank=1 has a smaller loop so it finished first, but the loop in rank=0 does not end.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thank you

Comment: `MPI_Win_fence()` is a collective operation that has to be invoked by all the ranks of the window. Consider using passive targets instead (TL;DR replace `MPI_Win_fence()` with `MPI_Win_lock()` and `MPI_Win_unlock()`)

Comment: What @GillesGouaillardet said. Or you could move the fences outside the loop and store your gets in an array. Btw, this program has magic numbers. Why is `N=5`? Your program will crash if you run it with more than 5 processes.